# PyQt5 | How to open a folder with a file preselected?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qdesktopservices

Currently I can open a folder by using

```
dirPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(self.oVidPath))
QDesktopServices.openUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile(dirPath))
```

I want to know if there is anyway I can open folder with a file preselected?

I am okay if it only works on linux systems (nautilus is preferred)

edit : This application is only going be for linux systems

Comment: you are talking about windows?

Comment: try run external command `explorer /e, /select, c:\windows\regedit.exe`

Comment: no I want this to work on linux systems mainly @TankSui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For windows

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.Qt import QProcess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    command = "explorer /e, /select, c:\\windows\\regedit.exe"
    process = QProcess()
    process.start(command)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

For Linux

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.Qt import QProcess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    command = "nautilus /var/log/dpkg.log"
    process = QProcess()
    process.start(command)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

FYI https://askubuntu.com/a/82717/249546

Comment: any way to do this on ubuntu?

Comment: i have tried it in ubuntu, what`s your concern now?

Comment: For pyqt5 on windows, only works when useing `process.startDetached(command)` other than `process.start(command)`. Still confused.